# jQuery check if all required inputs from a form are not empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes, required

Imagine a simple form with method `POST` and 30 inputs.

I would like to create a jQuery function that will be called from submit button. I searched about how to check all inputs that are required, but didn't find anything to help.

I would like something like this:

```
var inputs_required = all inputs from my form which have attribute required;
function check_required_inputs() {
   if(inputs_required != "") {
     //create ajax with serialize() and submit form;
   }
} else {
   //highlight inputs that are empty and show a message;
}
```

Can this be achieved in jQuery?

Comment: if your form has inputs with required you cannot submit the form and a message is show already by html5. you form will have a :valid and :invalid state to access via css

Comment: I know. You are right. As long as an input with attribute required is not filled, html5 should return error and highlight that error. Still, my form is submiting through ajax and the submit script is executing.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could give all your required inputs a common class (`required` for example) then use `each()` to loop through them like :

```
function check_required_inputs() {
    $('.required').each(function(){
        if( $(this).val() == "" ){
          alert('Please fill all the fields');

          return false;
        }
    });
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 19):

Zakaria already posted an answer, which should work great. Alternatively, instead of having a custom class, you could instead find all `input`, `textarea` and `select` elements that have the attribute `required` and are `visible` using

```
var required = $('input,textarea,select').filter('[required]:visible');
```

And then iterate through them using `each()` etc.

Example:

```
var allRequired = true;
required.each(function(){
    if($(this).val() == ''){
        allRequired = false;
    }
});

if(!allRequired){
    //DO SOMETHING HERE... POPUP AN ERROR MESSAGE, ALERT , ETC.
}
```

Comment: This is so simple and useful. With the :visible selector we make sure it gets only the inputs from the current tab.

Comment: This is an elegant answer to be certain.

Comment: great :) just note that the example will not work for select, as .val() does not provide value of select - need to get option:selected.

Answer (score 5):

```js
jQuery('button').on('click', function() {
  jQuery('input:invalid').css('background-color','red');
  jQuery('input:valid').css('background-color','green');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<input type="text" required="true" />
</form>
<button>click</button>
```

You simply give the inputs the `required="true"` attribute, then all empty required inputs will have the pseudo class `:invalid`.

`jQuery('input:invalid')` gives you a list of all invalid inputs. `.length` will give you the length of said list, if the length is > 0, your form is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this 
   assume that the form has an `ID` of form-action and submit button of `ID` form-
   submit.

```
var submitButton = $('#form-submit'),
    formContainer  = $('#form-action');

    submitButton.on('click',function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      formContainer.find('input').each(function(index,ele){
        if(ele.value === null || ele.value === ''){
            var error  = " the " + ele.name + " field  is requird ";
                ele.after(error);
           }
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also leverage the iterable function, [every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every), which will either return `true` only if **every** input validation is satisfied or `false` if otherwise:

```
function check_required_inputs() {
   var valid =  Array.prototype.every.call($('.required'), function(input) {
     return input.value;
   });

   if (valid) {
     return true;
   } else {
     alert('Please fill all the fields');

     return false;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I created this function which checks if the field is empty not only but if the user has inserted one or spaces without putting a character from a to b or other

```
function checkfield (champ)
{
var off='', isit=false;
for (var j=0; j <champ.val ().trim ().split (' ').length;j++)
{
off+=champ.val ().split (' ')[j];
}
off.replace (' ', '');
if (off.length==0) isit=true;
return isit;
}
```

to use :

example

```
if (checkfield ($('.class_of_field'))==true) return;
```